# How can this custom redux error middleware being invoked?

Tags: redux-middleware

Here is the source code.

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux'

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   ...
   if(action.type === 'E'){
      throw new Error("AAAAAAA")
   }
   return initialState;
}

const error = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
   try {
      next(action)
   } catch(e) {
      console.log("BBBBBB", e);
   }
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(error);

const store = createStore(reducer, 1, middleware);

store.subscribe(() => {
    ...
})

store.dispatch({type: "E"})
```

The result is `BBBBBB Error:AAAAAAA`

I thought that redux middleware is located between `store.dispatch()` and `reducer` which is inside of the store.

When we dispatch some action to the store, store's reducer is being invoked after middleware function's `next()`.

Am I wrong?

But how can that error middleware catch `e` nevertheless `throw new Error("AAAAAAA")` is located in reducer function?

You can see the above behavior in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ8fR0mZM44

In the video, the instructor says "The actual error never fired", but as the middleware logging the error object, failed to understand properly.